# Check values in JSON response in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to check status of protocol value true or not in JSON response. Below is the `params['protocol']` which return below response.

```
{"device1"=>true, "device2"=>false}
```

I need to  check if `device1` is true, I need to perform some operation. I am trying below code in controller but it is not working. How to implement this?

```
if params['protocol']["device1"] == "true"
```

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: yes.Working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try 
 `if params['protocol']["device1"] == true`

Note : `true` is without the quotes

Or if the value is always going to be boolean, you can simply do the following:

`if params['protocol']["device1"]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON to a hash and go with it.

```
# before this line, check if params['protocol'] actually exists.
protocol=JSON.parse(params['protocol']).with_indifferent_access

if protocol[:device1]
   # do your thing
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Below code is working.                                                                                  
 if params['protocol']["device1"] == true